# Issue installing Memcached for PHP5 CLI

Tags: php, memcached

I am having an issue install the memcached extension for PHP5 in CLI. I installed from source after trying pecl and having no luck whatsoever. For some reason it works with Apache but does not appear as a module that is loaded in CLI. I have added the extension to php.ini for CLI. Has anyone has this same issue before?

I am running Ubuntu 14 server. 
I installed PHP-5.5.15 from source with pthreads and pcntl enabled prior to trying to install memcached.

After installing I ran php -m from terminal to check whether the module was being loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install memcached
```

And compile the memcached extension to php5:

```
$ pecl download memcached
$ tar xvfz memcached-{{version}}.tgz
$ cd memcached-{{version}}/memcached-{{version}}
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

In your php.ini file add (default is /etc/php.ini):

```
extension = memcached.so
```

After instalation:

```
php --info | grep memcached
```

Comment: Tried this again, ran php -m and php -i and the results are the same. I think this may have something to do with a configuration setting in php.ini. I think it may not be pointed to the right folder for pear and therefore it is not seeing the extensions installed.
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I had set the configuration file path incorrectly when I compile PHP the first time. Moving the configuration file fixed the problem and the module loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses a different php.ini file for the CLI version. Check the location as this depends on your OS and PHP version.

I hope this helps you find the problem.

-Stefan